# java web application integration with java desktop application

Tags: java, web-applications

I am implementing java web application using JSP/Servlet. I have another standalone application on another machine.

When users of web application do something, I want to control / communicate with standalone application accordingly.

What are best ways to control / communicate with standalone application from web application deployed in tomcat?

One more thing, I do not want to use database things. Using database I want to avoid polling database from standalone application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider to use webservices to do the communication between two applications.

- Maybe it helps: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html
- introduction to webservices: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijti.html

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can I implement web service inside web application in Tomcat?

Comment: absolutely, if you are using java it is not very difficult and exist so much examples in the web.

Answer (score 1):

I think:
1) sharing the same DB
2) the desktop app polling (calling periodically
some web service) to get the web app's state

Theoretically you cannot access that easily a desktop app from a web app
(just because this desktop app may be sitting behind all kinds of firewalls and such).
The architectural choice here depends on many factors
like e.g. if both apps are in the same intranet or not.
If so 1) may be an option. Otherwise you could use 2).